# ActiveRecordで取得したobjectの、DBのカラムにない属性も含めてhashで取得したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

### Table

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMEN
  name VARCHAR(32),
);
```

### Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :hoge

  def set_hoge
    self.hoge = "hogehoge"
  end
end
```

### 実現したいこと

railsコマンドラインにて

```
> user = User.take
> user.set_hoge
> user.attributes
```

とすると、
{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Tom"}のように返されますが、

{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Tom", "hoge"=>"hogehoge"}
のように返す方法が知りたいです!
よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/51303

Answer (score 1):

as_jsonメソッドを用いると、インスタンスメソッドの結果を含めて返せます。

```
> user = User.take
> user.set_hoge
> user.as_json(methods: :hoge) # もしくは user.as_json(methods: [:hoge])
```